# User input in tkinter GUI determines how many words will be displayed in a pandas data table

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

The code I have so far is able to determine how the frequency of all non-stop words and symbols in a PDF, however I want the user to determine how many of these words are shown in the data table, not just all of them. For example, if there are 137 unique words in a PDF, but the user only wants to see 50, then the code will only show the 50 most frequent words in the PDF

The "Run" button in my program is what causes the code to execute after a file has been loaded in, so I decided to link the number the user inputs, as well as the the button to run the program together. I also tried a get opertaion but that also didn't work.

```
import os
import PyPDF2
import pandas
import webbrowser
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

#----Functions----#

#Method that a PDF that is read into the program goes through to eliminate any unwanted words or symbols#
def preprocess(text):
    #Filters out punctuation from paragraph witch becomes tokenized to words and punctuation#
    tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
    result = tokenizer.tokenize(text)

    #Makes all words lowercase#
    words = [item.lower() for item in result]

    #Removes all remaining tokens that are not alphabetic#
    result = [word for word in words if word.isalpha()]

    #Imports stopwords to be removed from paragraph#
    stop_words = set(stopwords.words("english"))

    #Removes the stop words from the paragraph#
    filtered_sent = []
    for w in result:
        if w not in stop_words:
            filtered_sent.append(w)

    #Return word to root word/chop-off derivational affixes#
    ps = PorterStemmer()
    stemmed_words = []
    for w in filtered_sent:
        stemmed_words.append(ps.stem(w))

    #Lemmatization, which reduces word to their base word, which is linguistically correct lemmas#
    lem = WordNetLemmatizer()
    lemmatized_words = ' '.join([lem.lemmatize(w,'n') and lem.lemmatize(w,'v') for w in filtered_sent])

    #Re-tokenize lemmatized words string#
    tokenized_word = word_tokenize(lemmatized_words)
    return tokenized_word

#Wraps two functions inside an object which allows both functions to use filename#
class PDFSelector:
    #Creates global variable 'filename'#
    def __init(self):
        self.filename = ''

    #Allows user to select PDF to use in program#
    def select_PDF(self):
        #Opens file directory to select a file, and shows both folders and PDF files only#
        self.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/", title = "Select file", filetypes = (("pdf files", "*.pdf"), ("all files", "*.*")))

    #Method for PDF to run through to convert it into text, then print it out in a browser#
    def run_program(self):    
        #Loads in PDF into program#
        PDF_file = open(self.filename, 'rb')
        read_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(PDF_file)

        #Determines number of pages in PDF file and sets the document content to 'null'#
        number_of_pages = read_pdf.getNumPages()
        doc_content = ""

        #Extract text from the PDF file#
        for i in range(number_of_pages):
            page = read_pdf.getPage(0)
            page_content = page.extractText()
            doc_content += page_content

        #Turns the text drawn from the PDF file into data the remaining code can understand#
        tokenized_words = preprocess(doc_content)

        #Determine frequency of words tokenized + lemmatized text#
        from nltk.probability import FreqDist
        fdist = FreqDist(tokenized_words)
        final_list = fdist.most_common(int(lbl2a.get()))

        #Organize data into two columns and export the data to an html that automatically opens#
        df = pandas.DataFrame(final_list, columns = ["Word", "Frequency"])
        df.to_html('word_frequency.html')
        webbrowser.open('file://' + os.path.realpath('word_frequency.html'))      

#----Main----#

#Creates an instance of the wrapped functions to use the GUI#        
selector = PDFSelector()

#Creats the GUI that will be used to select inputs#
window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("375x130")
window.resizable(0, 0)
window.title("Word Frequency Program")

#Code literally just to make the GUI look better#
lblfilla = tk.Label(window, text = "   ").grid(row = 0, column = 0)
lblfillb = tk.Label(window, text = "   ").grid(row = 0, column = 1)
lblfillc = tk.Label(window, text = "   ").grid(row = 0, column = 2)
lblfilld = tk.Label(window, text = "   ").grid(row = 0, column = 3)
lblfille = tk.Label(window, text = "   ").grid(row = 0, column = 4)
lblfillf = tk.Label(window, text = "   ").grid(row = 1, column = 0)
lblfillg = tk.Label(window, text = "   ").grid(row = 2, column = 0)
lblfillh = tk.Label(window, text = "   ").grid(row = 3, column = 0)
lblfilli = tk.Label(window, text = "   ").grid(row = 4, column = 0)

#Just a simple label on the GUI# (FILE NAME IS CURRENTLY NOT ABLE TO BE DISPLAYED)
lbl1 = tk.Label(window, text = "File Selected: ").grid(row = 1, column = 1)

#Label asking for input to determine number of words to be displayed in the data table# (NOT IMPLEMENTED YET)
lbl2 = tk.Label(window, text = "Number of Words: ").grid(row = 2, column = 1)
lbl2a = tk.Entry(window).grid(row = 2, column = 2)

#Calls the select_PDF method to choose a PDF for the program to read#
button1 = ttk.Button(window, text = "Select File", command = selector.select_PDF).grid(row = 1, column = 4)

#Button to make the program execute#
button2 = ttk.Button(window, text = "Run", command = selector.run_program).grid(row = 2, column = 4)

#Quits out of the program when certain button clicked#
button3 = ttk.Button(window, text = "Quit", command = window.quit).grid(row = 3, column = 2)

window.mainloop()
window.destroy()
```

Data table should show the number of words that the user input in the GUI, as well as those words' frequency in the PDF

Comment: ask a specific question or a specific problem

Comment: All of your widget variables, in particular `lbl2a`, are useless - they're all None (the result of calling `.grid()`) rather than the widgets themselves.  Most of the time, you don't actually need to keep a reference to widgets, but when you do, you have to do the geometry management as a separate statement.

Comment: @JakeP how to read user input from GUI (from lbl2a) to and have that user input be placed in `final_list = fdist.most_common(*user input data here*)`

Comment: @jasonharper are you saying I shouldn’t be using grid() but something else? Also how am I supposed to read in user input to make lbl2a not be None anymore?

Comment: if you use `var = Entry().grid()` then you have `None` in `var` because `grid()` returns `None` - and you can't get value from Entry. You have to do in two steps `var = Entry()` and `var.grid()`

Comment: what means "didn't work." ? Do you get error when you run it in console/terminal/cmd.exe ? Always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: @furas there was no error message, the program just crashed, also, I'll try what yo reccomend and see how it works

Comment: because you have `lbl2a = tk.Entry(...).grid(....)` so in `lbl2a` you have `None` instead of widget, and in `run_program` you should get error for `lbl2a.get()` - something about `NoneType` - because currently `lbl2a.get()` means `None.get()`

Comment: Oh okay, this is starting to make more sense now. So if I break those two apart, I should be one step closer to having it execute properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only had to make two small corrections to two seperate areas of code
first:

```
lbl2 = tk.Label(window, text = "Number of Words: ").grid(row = 2, column = 1)
lbl2a = tk.Entry(window).grid(row = 2, column = 2)
```

was changed to this because the grid returned `None`, so I had to seperate the two for the entry to work and not recognize the entry as `None`:

```
lbl2 = tk.Label(window, text = "Number of Words: ").grid(row = 2, column = 1)
user_input = tk.Entry(window)
user_input.grid(row = 2, column = 2)
```

and this:

```
from nltk.probability import FreqDist
fdist = FreqDist(tokenized_words)
final_list = fdist.most_common(int(lbl2a.get()))
```

was changed to this beause I moved the import to the top, as well as changed the name of lbl2a to user_input. Also, the program recognizes the value the user inputs as a string, so I converted it to an int in the run_program method:

```
fdist = FreqDist(tokenized_words)
final_list = fdist.most_common(int(user_input.get()))
```

This answer came from @**furas**, I just wanted to provide it in case anyone else happens upon the same problem I have